# How to make transparency image, that it doesn't cover part of printing side

Tags: c#

I explain everything with images which I enclosed:

Screenshot 1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Sb9.png)

I ask someone for signature. The problem is, this signature covers a part of document to print it out. How to make the background transparent, taking the image directly from picturebox.Image1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY6eM.png)

How to avoid that the signature not covers part of document. A part of code:

```
private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{ 
    Image img = Image.FromFile("kartaWyjazd2.jpg"); // the main document
    Point loc = new Point(10,10);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);

    var imageList = pictureBox1.Image;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList, 450,1040); // second image with signature
}
```

Comment: How to you capture the signature? Perhaps in the control where the user draws the signature, you can specify its background to be transparent. Otherwise, you'd have to loop through the signature's bitmap pixels and replace every occurrence of white with transparent.

Comment: I set it to transparent background but it doesn't help

Comment: I think this is what you need, look at the example code. In your case, it would be to remap white to transparent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes.setremaptable?view=netframework-4.5.2#System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageAttributes_SetRemapTable_System_Drawing_Imaging_ColorMap___System_Drawing_Imaging_ColorAdjustType_

Comment: The 2nd image need transparency, ie it must be created as eg 32argb, maybe saved as PNG (not jpg) and the Graphics should have Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver; ( Remapping white will miss all antialiased pixels..)

Comment: That could help thank you :)